# Public property inaccessible in public method

Tags: php, oop

I'm very new to Php OOP and am getting stuck on one particular problem. I have trawled stackoverflow to try and find an answer, but can't. I've spent over an hour on this one problem and am about ready to give up. I know a Php guru will see my issue straight away, so please tell me why this class won't work.

```
 <?php
class tester{
    public $testproperty;
    public function testfunction(){
        $this->$testproperty = 'Nothing';
        return $this->$testproperty;
    }
}
$object = new tester();
echo $object->testfunction();
?>
```

Comment: As it turns out, I have been using $ for some and for others not. Atleast I have learnt something for the future now :). Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->testproperty; //without $
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$this->$testproperty
```

to

```
$this->testproperty
```

Always read manual on the subject first.

Comment: Thanks, I did read the manual but the dollar sign was something I totally overlooked.